# Language File Issue (File Manager Related)

Tags: control-panel, updating, file-manager, multi-language

I am working on a site that I recently updated from 2.1.4 to 2.5.5. I am noticing that certain menu titles and field titles associated with the file manager module are not being pulled from the language files correctly.

Has anyone else seen this issue and/or found a fix for it?

[image: Here is a screengrab showing what I mean]

Comment: Did you upload the 2.5.5 **cp_themes** folder? Some language keys may have changed.

Comment: Pretty sure I did - will double check just now...

Comment: Yup - I just re-uploaded the cp_themes folder, cleared caches etc and tried again... still the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed - I uploaded the language folder within system again, overwriting everything. It appears to be working now. Not sure what I did during the update then!?